# Sensitivity of latent heat of fusion of ice on temperature and pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, water, fusion, ice

The enthalpy of fusion is the heat necessary to convert 1 kg of ice to liquid water. According to Wikipedia, this heat equals 333,55 kJ/kg.

Does this heat change with the temperature or pressure and if so, are there any correlations that model this dependence?

I am really looking for experimental measurements for different temperatures and pressures. It would be nice to have an expression for the latent heat in function of pressure, temperature.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64031/what-is-the-effect-of-an-increase-in-pressure-on-latent-heat-of-vaporization and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30332/heat-of-vaporization-of-water-dependence-on-relative-humidity?rq=1

Comment: Yes thank you for those links, but however they do not answer my question in case of fusion.

Comment: Are you asking for experimental measurements of the change in latent heat, or for theoretical approaches such as [Kirchoff's law](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Thermodynamics/Energies_and_Potentials/Enthalpy/Kirchhoff_Law)?

Comment: I am really looking for experimental measurements for different temperatures and pressures. It would be nice to have an expression for the latent heat in function of pressure, temperature.

Comment: It's no problem finding that information for latent heat of vaporization, since steam is so commonly used for engineering purposes.  If I had my old textbooks with me, I would look through to see if any had it tabulated for fusion with the other water information.

Comment: @JMac Yes indeed, I needed that information as well and found it easily, but it’s really hard to find for fusion :-(

Answer (score 1):

The heat of fusion of ice needs to change with pressure because the equilibrium freezing temperature changes with pressure. The combined effect assures the entropy of a mole of water/ice a function of state, so that the integral dQ/T around a closed path on a pressure-volume diagram is zero with reversible heat exchange, the same as for a Carnot cycle. Unfortunately, I don't know how to observe this with simple lab equipment, the way you can measure the heat of fusion at ambient pressure.